# Different State of ExternalStorageState

Tags: android

Explain in which situation (ex:phone connected as media to computer, SD card unmounted), below conditions will be met.

```
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        // Can read and write the media
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        // Can only read the media
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    } else {
        // Can't read or write
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

  if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    // We can read and write the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
} else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    // We can only read the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
} else {
    // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
    //  to know is we can neither read nor write
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
}
```

This will check whether the external storage is available to read and write. The `getExternalStorageState()` method returns other states that you might want to check, such as whether the media is being shared (connected to a computer), is missing entirely, has been removed badly, etc. You can use these to notify the user with more information when your application needs to access the media.

**Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED**

```
Check Storage state if the media is present and mounted at its mount point with read/write access. 
It will be true if the SD card is available.
```

**Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY**

```
It will true if sdcard is available and its Read only.
```

Comment: If your SD card is only read-only. And you have not provided the right to access it when connected to the system from your device settings.